# Test class for switch java

Tags: java

I want to create a test class in eclipse for the following code in java how can i do that??

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refactor your code. Move this code to a separate method. Call that method with different values.

Comment: Can you please show me how??

Comment: No, that would be too easy. Go through a basic java tutorial on methods.

Comment: A little more detail: Move your whole switch statements to a different method that takes an int argument and returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make your code testable. Best code for tests is a method that gets parameters and returns result without using a context. It's your case!

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert "August".equals(monthByNumber(8));
        assert "Invalid month".equals(monthByNumber(13));
    }

    private static String monthByNumber(int month) {
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                break;
        }
        return monthString;
    }
}
```

Then just use `assert` or JUnit framework, like in answer of Jakub Hr.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code contains hardcoded value 8 and it always return August.
But it doesn't mean that you can't write a test, especially using TDD.

So let's write test first:

```
public class SwitchDemoTest {

    @Test
    public void getMonthShouldReturnAugustWhenParameterIs8() {
        final String result = SwitchDemo.getMonth(8);
        Assert.assertEquals("August", result);
    }
}
```

After that your code doesn't compile so you have to add static `getMonth` method which accepts `int` parameter.

Than you can continue and write another test which forces you to get rid of hardcoded value etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SwitchDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int monthNum     = 8;
    String monthText = "";

    //Call #1
    monthText = getMonthText(monthNum);
    System.out.println(monthText);

    //Call #2
    System.out.println(getMonthText(monthNum));
}

//Extract to function for reuse
public static String getMonthText(int monthNumber){
    String monthString = "";
    switch (monthNumber) {
        //No need to break out of the case since return automatically breaks out of function
        case 1:  return "January";
        case 2:  return "February";
        case 3:  return "March";
        case 4:  return "April";
        case 5:  return "May";
        case 6:  return "June";
        case 7:  return "July";
        case 8:  return "August";
        case 9:  return "September";
        case 10: return "October";
        case 11: return "November";
        case 12: return "December";
        default: return "Invalid month";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove main() method with another method like:

```
public static String monthOfYear(int month){
String monthString;
switch(month){
//your code until the last break; statement
}
return monthString;
}
```

you can access this using:
System.out.print(SwitchDemo.monthOfYear(8)); where SwitchDemo is the class that contains the
above method